# Heating effect of fast neutrons in Fast Breeder Reactors

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, power, neutrons, nuclear-engineering

Do fast neutrons play effective(meaningful) role in heating up the water in Fast Breeder Reactors? If so, how much do they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only indirectly, and not in the same fashion as a normal reactor.

Normally the chain reaction in a fission reactor is only sustainable by thermalized neutrons, otherwise, they pretty much go right by the nuclei. The cross section is much higher at thermal energies. Since the easiest solution to thermalizing is to just put the whole thing in water, the nice side-effect of the design is that you get hot water out.

The whole idea of any fast reactor, breeder or not, is to enrich the fuel so the now-lower chance of absorption is offset by the much greater chance of meeting a nucleus that will absorb you. So this normally means greatly increasing the amount of U235. This does NOT imply that you can't moderate it too, but you don't HAVE to. For designs where size is more important than anything else, this is a good way to go because you get rid of a lot of the water plumbing. This is used on submarines for instance.

But if your goal is breeding, then you have two jobs. One is to keep the chain reaction going, and the other, and this is the hard part, is getting some of those high-energy neutrons out to do the breeding in the blanket. In this case, you want to avoid any moderation if possible. That means an even smaller core so you don't slow things down too much thermalizing the core itself, and the absence of any other moderators between the core and the blanket.

Now I say indirectly because the blanket is then cooled and used to generate power. That cooling water is not a moderator, just a coolant, and there are of course alternate designs like sodium or lead cooling that allow the core to be actively cooled. But even these often have a secondary water cooling system, outside the blanket. So ultimate the cooling is water at some point, perhaps in the primary loop, but more likely in the secondary, but its not a moderator as well.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I had forgotten that FBR doesn't use cooler, and use something like liquid sodium, at the question time. However, you pointed that to me out. Now, can I regard "The fast neutrons in a fast breeder reactor are used to generate power" a true statement?

Comment: Yes, but again, in the fast breeder much of that energy is (hopefully!) used in the breeding process first. But ultimately, energy is energy at the inlet to the steam generator!